# Why modx doesn`t reg js and css

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I heve a problem with my modx site. It isn`t register any js and css with regClientScript(), regClientCSS() or regClientStartupScript(). Just do nothing. I have this with pdoPage and other snippets and plugins where using regClient..().
When i call getRegisteredClientStartupScripts() there is return nothing.
I have no idea whats happened with modx. Help please.

Call pdoPage

```
<div id="pdopage">
<div class="rows">
    [[!pdoPage?
        &parents=`0`
        &ajaxMode=`default`
        &tpl=`@INLINE <p>[[+idx]]</p>`
    ]]
</div>
[[!+page.nav]]
```

[Strucuture document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myvBK.png])

I try did this in plugin

```
switch ($modx->event->name) { 
case "OnLoadWebDocument": 
  $modx->regClientCSS('assets/css/style.css');
  $modx->regClientScript('assets/js/script.js');
  break;
}
```

Same result.

Comment: Can you show us code example of yours?

Comment: thank you for answer. I add some code in question.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the following plugin code:

```
switch ($modx->event->name) { 
case "OnWebPagePrerender": 
  $modx->regClientCSS('assets/css/style.css');
  $modx->regClientScript('assets/js/script.js');
  break;
}
```

The event you are looking for is `OnWebPagePrerender`